# What's the difference between Fusion API and Optimizer API in MOSEK?

Tags: api, convex-optimization, mosek

The MOSEK solver has two APIs, one is the Fusion API and the other is the Optimizer API. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fusion API calls the optimize API so the optimizer API is more general. However, Fusion is a high-level API and hence is easier to use.

Btw in the just released MOSEK v10.0 then the optimizer API has something called affine conic constraints that will make it easier to use for conic
problems. I.e. the optimizer API obtains some of the Fusion features.